# Get max value of a column in my source table in Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have the following table with the shown data in it:

```
send_date  |  household_ID
-------------------------
11-20-2014 | 123
11-20-2014 | 456
11-15-2014 | 789
```

I need to do 2 things:

1) Calculate the max value for send_date

2) Filter out any rows whose send_date does not match that value

In other words, I want the output to be:

```
send_date  |  household_ID
-------------------------
11-20-2014 | 123
11-20-2014 | 456
```

Row number 3 should be filtered out as its send_date is not the max.

I tried creating an aggregate, grouping by all columns, and creating a new output port called `MAX_DATE` with an expression of `MAX(SEND_DATE)`, then have a filter transformation with the condition `MAX_DATE = SEND_DATE`

This lets all rows through, though.  What can I do to make this work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use two source qualifiers for the same source table or - better yet - stay with a single SQ but split data into two pipelines (see the comment below for details).
- Calculate `MAX_DATE` value using the first one and an aggregator.
- Then join data from the second source qualifier on the `SEND_DATE` column.

Comment: Why read data twice? Use one SQ, split the flow into two. Use aggregatro to get max date as you've mentioned and do a self join with the other pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion, the simplest way to solve the issue is to use RANK transformation.
Advantage:
 - No splits in SQ
 - No joins after aggregation
 - Simple :)
The transformation is ranking top/bottom (according your configuration; you need to choose "Top")
So, it will pass through the whole row then the maximal send_date value will be ranked as 1.
The next step is to filter all rows with the rank greater than 1.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is not what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `send_date` <> (SELECT MAX(`send_date`) FROM `table`)
```

Or, if I misunderstood you, then:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `send_date` = (SELECT MAX(`send_date`) FROM `table`)
```

Comment: No need of `limit 1` in inner query since `max` will return a scalar data.

Comment: @Rahul thanks. I will edit my answer to remove the limit. Still not so sure if I understood the question.